# Будет ли это замыкание?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Ребята, если я экспортирую функцию `print` и вызову её в файле `index.js` - это будет замыканием?

```
const number = 0;

const print = () => {
  console.log(number)
};

export { print }
```

Comment: Это будет экспорт функции))

Answer (score 5):

Да, это замыкание. Документация [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) утверждает:

> In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created,
> at function creation time.

Другое дело, что это замыкание не ссылается на локальные переменные других функций, так что оно может быть оптимизировано и удалено. Получится обычная функция, которая ссылается только на глобальные объекты.

Если не прикрываться документацией, то можно сказать что в этом случае замыкание не нужно и может быть удалено.

**P.S.** `number` не глобальная переменная, а переменная модуля. Но чтобы хранить на неё ссылку, замыкание не нужно. Эта переменная живёт вечно, при компиляции функции можно установить на неё ссылку, которая ничем не будет отличаться от ссылки на глобальные объекты.

Comment: Это модуль - переменная не глобальная.

Comment: Переменные модулей попадают в ту же категорию переменных, время жизни которых можно считать бесконечным.

Comment: Почему? Если экспортируются, то логично, а если нет, то похожи на локальные. Впрочем, формально они всё равно должны замыканием удерживаться, если там есть экспортируемые функции. UPDATE: Хотя, там вроде что-то про слоты говорилось, но разве это не только к экспортируемым и импортируемым сущностям относится?

Comment: Если вы сослались на локальную переменную, её помещают в замыкание. Если потеряете все ссылки на все функции ссылающиеся на тот же контекст, сборщик мусора уберёт замыкание. Если вы ссылаетесь на переменную модуля, этот механизм бесполезен. Переменную модуля никто удалять не будет - на неё есть ссылка в экспортированной функции (если ссылки нет, другой разговор, тогда компилятор может выкинуть весь недоступный код до загрузки модуля в память).

Comment: Но ведь замыкание работает точно так же?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да. Исторически все контексты всех функций хранились на стеке. Локальные переменные жили столько сколько длился вызов функции. По этой причине в C нет замыканий, а в C++ лямбду нельзя вернуть из функции где она создана. В JavaScript замыкания выделяются в динамической памяти, и могут жить столько сколько угодно программисту. То есть, замыкание мало отличается от объекта. Я хочу сказать этот сложный механизм не нужен, если вы ссылаетесь на глобальные и модульные объекты.